# Retrieve MySQL insert id in Meteor method

Tags: mysql, node.js, meteor

I am relatively new to Node and Meteor and am trying to retrieve the insert ID of a MySQL query using the numtal:mysql package. The trouble I run into is the query function running on the server and not returning to the client. I need the ID to return to the client so I can route the client to the newly created entry.

Client:

```
Template.new.events({
  'click .button.submit' : function(){
    Meteor.call('demoFunc', function(error, result){
      console.log(result);
    });
  },
});
```

Server:

```
Meteor.methods({
  demoFunc:function(){
    //construct deal object
    var newDeal = {
      dealer_id : 1,
      client_id : 1
    };

    //deal query
    liveDb.db.query('INSERT INTO deal SET ?', newDeal, function(err, result){
      return result.returnId;
    });
  }

});
```

If I could get the *result.returnId* in the *demoFunc* method to return to the client then I would be golden. If anyone's run into anything like this or worked around this, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The best place to ask that is at https://github.com/numtel/meteor-mysql/issues

This is a community packages and I highly recommend not to use it in production, only for learning/fun. You can also contribute to this repo by adding that feature that you want.

It is expect that Meteor will support MySQL soon. Meteor bought Fatomdb: http://techcrunch.com/2014/10/07/meteor-acquires-yc-alum-fathomdb-for-its-web-development-platform/

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same issue and solved the problem with this package [usefulio:sync-methods](https://atmospherejs.com/usefulio/sync-methods). You can see how the package works in [Github](https://github.com/ianserlin/meteor-sync-methods).

This package automatically adds a callback function to every syncMethod defined in server side. So, you can just call this callback function from inside the server method, after the async results have been processed.

So, the steps are:

1) Install the package: meteor add usefulio:sync-methods

2) Declare your method as a syncMethod like this:

```
Meteor.syncMethods({
  demoFunc:function(callback){
    //construct deal object
    var newDeal = { dealer_id : 1, client_id : 1 };

    //deal query
    liveDb.db.query('INSERT INTO deal SET ?', newDeal, function(err, result){
      callback(undefined, result.returnId);
    });
  }

});
```

3) On the client side, you just call the method in the Meteor way:

```
Meteor.call('demoFunc', function(err, result){
    ...
});
```